# In API design, if I request a list of objects by ID, and one of those IDs is invalid/deleted, should the request fail?

Tags: api, api-design

Let's say I'm requesting a list of IDs for which I'd like to receive relevant DB entities (e.g., `my-restaurant-api.com?restaurants=1,2,3`).

In this example, let's say ID 3 has been deleted and should not be returned.

Should the API response:

1. return a 404
2. return a 200 and include the entities that exist
3. return a 404 and include entities that exist
4. return a 200 and include an exception message and entities that exist

Or, in this case, should it be up to the consumer to determine what's best for the application? Is there a *right* answer?

Comment: As with many things in software engineering, there is no single right answer. It can be different depending on the requirements for the application.

Comment: Depends, but, usually, you'd think about what is most "friendly" to the user.  A plain 404 is unhelpful and would be eliminated.  Unless your restaurants are really secret MI-6 bases, in which case 404 is most "secure".

Comment: Is it more useful to a client for your endpoint to return the entities that exist, or to return nothing at all?

Comment: See Robert's comment, and if I have 100 IDs and want all existing IDs, how am I supposed to get this if you return errors and no information?

Comment: Customarily – if the user provides "a list," return "a list" which contains an equal number of entries.  If the record no longer exists, the response for that ID is that the ID is no longer valid.  If it does, the response is the requested information for that ID.  The request is `200 OK` because it could be, and was, successfully answered.  I would use `404 Not Found` only to indicate that the REST-API did not exist at all.

Answer (score 2):

Return `200 OK` and (optionally) include some status information in your JSON indicating that some of the entities no longer exist.

If you return no entities, you force your user to create a new request that excludes the missing entities.  Just note in your documentation that your endpoint will not return entities that no longer exist, which is the most intuitive behavior anyway.

Comment: Are you saying there is never a case where you want a complete set of the things? Sure the calling app could double check to make sure it got all the wheels for the car, or whatever and not just loop through the results assuming they all got sent. But I'm not sure I would call that good design

Comment: While I agree with this answer I would suggest considering an "adaptation" of the `206 Partial Content` [status code](https://httpstatuses.com/206) to indicate success, but an incomplete response. Even though the spec says it should be used with the `Range` HTTP header with clear documentation I would argue this could work ;)

Comment: @AnotherGuy: I already made that suggestion elsewhere in this post.  The problem with using HTTP status codes in this context is that the "error" is actually an application problem, not a problem having to do with HTTP.  The only thing 206 actually has in common with this issue is the words "partial content."

Answer (score 1):

Let the client specify using an HTTP header how strict to be (for example in OData there is a “continue-on-error” header for batch requests).

If the client doesn’t want strict mode simply return 200 with the existing entities.

If the client wants the strict mode, return 400 with the valid entities and error information indicating which entities were not found.

The reason I’d suggest 400 instead of 404, is that your IDs are part of the query and not part of the URL path. So it’s not like the client tried to access a “resource” that doesn’t exist (in the strictest sense), it’s just that some data in the request is invalid. If the ID was part of the URL path, then 404 would be more appropriate. I do however acknowledge there’s a fine line here and this is somewhat open to interpretation.

Comment: Returning 400 seems strange to me. It’s not actually a bad request. That id may have been available 2 minutes ago and then deleted by another client. In a more common situation where the client request a single id, you wouldn’t return a 400 either right? At least I would find that extremely unintuitive.

Comment: I don’t find it unintuitive, but that’s fine if you do. Do what you like. Like I said this is somewhat open to interpretation. This is a rather opinion based thing which I don’t like and I why I added the disclaimer.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, an URL incl. any query parameters should represent a *resource*. But your URL represents a collection of resources. This kind of batch requests is common, but as far as HTTP is concerned you are now on your own. There is no obviously good approach to handle partial failure of a batch request.

A couple of solutions:

- Don't do batch requests at all. Thanks to HTTP/2 you can send multiple requests over the same connection in parallel, and thanks to async programming it has become easier to handle multiple pending requests efficiently. One advantage is that responses won't be delayed if one element in the collection takes longer.
- Think more carefully about how the API would be used, and have any response codes refer to the collection, rather than to the elements in the collection. Would the collection be unusable if any element is missing? If so, choose an 4xx error. Or is failure of one sub-request acceptable? If so, just mark the element as missing in the (otherwise successful) response.
- Accept that you are doing batch-requests, and place the sub-responses into an envelope that handles failures on an individual level. So effectively, invent your own protocol on top of HTTP. The HTTP status code is then mostly irrelevant. For example, your request might return:

  ```json
  [
    { "id": "1", "success": true, "data": { ... } },
    { "id": "2", "success": true, "data": { ... } },
    { "id": "3", "success": false, "error": "..." }
  ]
  ```
- Instead of creating your own protocol on top of a pseudo-REST API, use an existing approach like GraphQL.

Answer (score -4):

ok lets break this down. You quote the url:

```
my-restaurant-api.com?restaurants=1,2,3
```

lets correct the obvious errors with this. First the missing protocol and slashes

```
https://my-restaurant-api.com/?restaurants=1,2,3
```

Now lets add a path, or 'resource'

```
https://my-restaurant-api.com/restaurants/id=1,2,3
```

Now the query string is problematic. The id isnt "1,2,3" so the correct structure is:

```
?id=1&id=2&id=3
```

But you can see how this can easily run into url max length issues. Best practice is to send it in the body and when sending a body you should be POSTing. Since your not POSTing a restaurant we will want to change the path to something that matches what we are trying to do, so:

```
POST https://my-restaurant-api.com/GetRestaurantsByIds

{
    "Ids" : ["1","2","3"]
}
```

Only now can we start talking about sensible errors.

First off never use 404 to indicate "you hit the right endpoint but the result of the operation was an empty set". So thats right out

A non error response is a JSON array of restaurant objects right? so an empty array is the correct "nothing found" response.

Now for the case of partial results we could either treat the request as a search, "select * from restaurants where id in (...)", in which case returning an empty or partial response would be expected.

OR we could treat it like a command "My top 3 restaurants are these!" and we would expect an error if there were only two. eg

```
500 restaurant 3 not found, you must specify 3 restaurants
```

You might reflect the expected behaviour in your choice of path name

```
SearchRestaurantsByID //expect 200 empty set or partial result
```

vs

```
GetCompleteRestaurantSet // expect 500 error message
```

But obviously your documentation would make it totally clear.

Comment: You never got to the "correct" status code to use.  It's not 500; a valid result was returned.

Comment: @robertharvey my meaning is that either the 500 error or the 200 empty set is correct depending on the meaing of the query as discussed

Comment: 200 is much better.  I'd even accept a 206 Partial Content.

Comment: I guess, if the client gets the content though what are they going to do with the response code?

Comment: Nothing.  Personally, I think HTTP  status codes are overrated and programmers spend too much time thinking about them.

Comment: also does 206 mean 3 exists, I just havent sent it, or 3 doesnt exist, returning the rest?? I like to stick with 200 and 500.

Comment: 500 is definitely wrong here, there was no unknowm server error.

Comment: You are right (as usual) we should get back to spaces vs tabs ;)

Comment: 500 Internal Server Error doesn't seem appropriate at all.  You generally only see that when something really bad has happened on the server side and the application cannot respond in any meaningful way.

Comment: well yes, if your app throws an exception attempting to return the "CompleteRestarantSet" I think 500 is the correct response code

Comment: Under those conditions I don't think you would get any data back at all.

Comment: yes. that is what I said wasnt it? either 200 + data or 500 + error

Comment: Returning no data at all if one element no longer exists doesn't sound like a very good strategy to me.  You return what you have.  Even if you return no data, it's still not a catastrophic error, which is what 500 is.

Comment: shrug, the OP lists it as an option and doesnt really go into what the command is supposed to do. I can see there might be cases where you need all results or nothing, hence the either / or

Comment: Many of your "obvious errors" are not errors but stylistic differences

Comment: Since it was a client error, a 4xx code would be reasonable, if you don't go for 200 or 206

Comment: @user949300: Which one?

Comment: @whatsisnane hmm my intention was only the first correction was an "obvious error" but I have become bored of editing it now.

Comment: my point was that once you start filling in the missing bits your various options with different paths and methods open up

Comment: @user949300 maybe you could interpret it as a client error, but I think its a bit of a stretch. save em for the actual protocol errors

Comment: @RobertHarvey (and Ewan) on further review, most of the 400s are a "bit off" for this.  Geez the docs are confusing.  I'll vote for 418.  :-). All im sure of is that 500 is wrong.

Comment: @user949300 are you saying 500 is not the correct response when the api code would throw an exception?